# C++ merge sort passed by value

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to recursively implement the merge sort algorithm by only passing in a vector value to the function (no left or right index). The while loop in the following code works when the list to be sorted is passed as a pointer `void merge_sort_array(int* v, int l, int r)` or reference `void merge_sort_ref(vector<int>& v, int l, int r)` but I cannot for the life of me understand why the following code will not properly sort my list. I have a feeling it is something to do with either the starting values of `i, j, k` or the bounds within my while loop but I've tried anything that makes sense to me and can't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
vector<int> merge_sort_value(vector<int> v) {
    int n = v.size();
    if(n == 1){
        return v;
    }
    else{
        int m = n/2;
        vector<int> v1(v.begin(), v.begin()+m);
        vector<int> v2(v.begin()+m, v.begin()+n);
        merge_sort_value(v1);
        merge_sort_value(v2);
        vector<int> tmp(v.begin(), v.begin()+m);
        int i = 0;
        int j = m;
        int k = 0;
        while((i < m) or (j < n)){
            if(i == m){
                v[k] = v[j];
                j +=1;
            }
            else if((j == n) or (tmp[i] < v[j])){
                v[k] = tmp[i];
                i+=1;
            }
            else{
                v[k] = v[j];
                j+=1;
            }
            k+=1;
            # print output for debugging
            for(auto x = v.begin(); x != v.end(); ++x)
                cout << *x << " ";
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout <<  i << "\t"<< j << "\t" << k << endl;
        }
        return v;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> v(10);

    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
      v[i] = rand() % 100;

    v = merge_sort_value(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I have included a sample output for reference below:

```
28 28 
0   2   1
28 80 
1   2   2
21 21 
0   2   1
21 92 
1   2   2
14 92 21 
1   1   1
14 92 21 
1   2   2
14 92 21 
1   3   3
14 28 14 92 21 
0   3   1
14 80 14 92 21 
1   3   2
14 80 28 92 21 
2   3   3
14 80 28 92 21 
2   4   4
14 80 28 92 21 
2   5   5
21 57 
1   1   1
21 57 
1   2   2
78 83 
1   1   1
78 83 
1   2   2
78 78 83 
0   2   1
78 83 83 
0   3   2
78 83 96 
1   3   3
21 57 96 78 83 
1   2   1
21 57 96 78 83 
2   2   2
21 57 96 78 83 
2   3   3
21 57 96 78 83 
2   4   4
21 57 96 78 83 
2   5   5
21 28 14 92 21 21 57 96 78 83 
0   6   1
21 57 14 92 21 21 57 96 78 83 
0   7   2
21 57 80 92 21 21 57 96 78 83 
1   7   3
21 57 80 28 21 21 57 96 78 83 
2   7   4
21 57 80 28 14 21 57 96 78 83 
3   7   5
21 57 80 28 14 92 57 96 78 83 
4   7   6
21 57 80 28 14 92 21 96 78 83 
5   7   7
21 57 80 28 14 92 21 96 78 83 
5   8   8
21 57 80 28 14 92 21 96 78 83 
5   9   9
21 57 80 28 14 92 21 96 78 83 
5   10  10
```

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

after reviewing you code it seems you're making mistakes in the algorithm it self and in C++ as language so i've edited your algorithm to be more neat and more readable algorithm i will explain some part of the code

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
vector<int> merge_sort_value(vector<int> v) {
  int n = v.size();
  if(n == 1){
    return v;
  }
  else{
    int m = n/2;
    vector<int> v1(v.begin(), v.begin()+m);
    vector<int> v2(v.begin()+m, v.begin()+n);
    v1 = merge_sort_value(v1); /* passing by value will left v1 with no sorting so you need to copy from the returned
    object */
    v2 = merge_sort_value(v2);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    const size_t left_vecS = v1.size();
    const size_t right_vecS = v2.size();

    while (i<left_vecS&&j<right_vecS) { // we must keep i (AND) j  valid
      if (v1[i] < v2[j])
        v[k++] = v1[i++];

      else
        v[k++] = v2[j++];
    }

      while(i<left_vecS) // if we sorted v2 then what insert the rest of v1 in v as what kept from v1 will be sorted
        v[k++] = v1[i++];


      while(j<right_vecS)
        v[k++] = v2[j++];
    }
    return v;
  }


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  vector<int> v(10);
  std::vector<int> x;

  for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    v[i] = rand() % 100;

  v = merge_sort_value(v);

  for(auto&i:v)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**1-** I get rid of the printing inside the sorting function so we keep the code clean

**2-** 
 the first error you've did at the language level is you didn't copy the returned sorted vector object from `merge_sort_value` to the vectors.(i've mentioned that in the code in a comment) so that's the first thing to keep in mind

**3-** the logic part of the algorithm wasn't clear to me because i didn't see how you're sorting specially that part `else if ((j == n) or (tmp[i] < v[j])) {
        v[k] = tmp[i];
        i += 1;
      }`

like you're comparing unsorted sub vector to another unsorted vector and you're giving it unsorted value again (you must compare v1 against v2)
the whole logic is missed up i think you need to review it

anyway i hope that helped